# using load and delay to control fetching data in apollo

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

I try to use the Query component to fetch data when for example when for example a button is clicked. The problem is that the Query component fetch data immediately. 
I saw in the doc that we can control the fetching of the data using the load function provided to children and the delay property of Query component but I haven't succeeded to do it right.
so has has someone done something similar?

Comment: post some code so we have a reference point from which to help

Comment: un issue describing the same problem I have here: https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues/1875